# Magento2 Malware and security issues

Tags: magento2, security, vulnerability, malware

We noticing since last few months that Magento instances are affecting of malware on the Magento2 sites? For example:

1. health_check.php attack - this file compromised
2. Credit card fields were update with "_hook" post fix

Please let us know if someone has more information on such malware attacks. Is there any fixes?

Magento releasing patches very frequently, are they considering above malware?

Thanks.

Comment: See here for the most common recent attacks https://sansec.io/research/magento-2-template-attacks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the security update **APSB22-12**.
[How to prevent the infection of `pub/health_check.php` in **2.3.3-p1 ≤** Magento **≤ 2.3.7-p2** and **2.4.0 ≤** Magento **≤ 2.4.3-p1**](https://mage2.pro/t/6396).